# Changing CSS with jQuery on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got the following code: it changes the position of some navigation elements, depending on the browser width.

It does this by using `$(window).width()`, and then making the change in pixels (not percentages). This works great. However, when the user changes the browser window, the calculations are off.

Is there a way for me to refire the css changes on browser resize -- or just reload the div? Reloading the page on resize works okay, but it's only a small div that needs fixing.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('archive') >= 0) {
    archive.css({left: nw / 2 - aw / 2});
    films.css({right: - nw / 2 - fw / 2});
        $('.index').css({left: nw / 2 - iw / 2 });

} else if (window.location.href.indexOf('films') >= 0) {
    archive.css({left: - nw / 2 - aw / 2});
    films.css({right:  nw / 2 - fw / 2});
        $('a.index').css({left: - nw / 2 + iw / 2 });
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf('index') >= 0) {


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // do something on resize
});
```

should do the trick.

By the way, CSS media queries could be a better choice.

Comment: Hmm, if I wrap the above code in the window.resize, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It should. Post all your code, I don't have enough to help you.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to put the corresponding variables in with the resize. That seems to link it all up. Many thanks.